# Will Google be able to access my website after blocking all US IPs?

Tags: .htaccess, googlebot

I'm going to block all US IPs using .htaccess this way :

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order deny,allow
deny from 3.0.0.0/8
deny from 4.0.0.0/25
deny from 4.0.0.128/26
deny from 4.0.0.192/28
deny from 4.0.0.208/29
....
allow from all
</Limit>
```

Will Google be able to access and index my website after blocking all US IPs?

**EDIT :** Sorry for the ambiguity, but **I DO want** Google to index my website.

Comment: Propably yes. Have you considered using a robots.txt?

Comment: This assumes the following is correct: 1. Google will only crawl from a US address (Google has data centers in many countries) 2. Your "US address" list is 100% accurate (I guarantee it is not)

Comment: My bad I edited my question. I do want Google to index my website however I don't want US visitors to be on my website at the moment for some technical reasons.

Comment: Yes, it can probably still index it.

Comment: "Probably" is not enough for me :p

Comment: Location-based lockouts are a HORRIBLE idea. Just put a notice that you don't do business with people from the US or whatever your site is about.

Comment: Please, consider an up vote to make up for my loss of bounty. Since, you were unable to review my answer in time I lost half of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although Google has its servers spread across the whole world, it would be quite hard to say where the search engine's bots mostly originate from. What I suggest would be to block the IP ranges but add an exclusion clause that matches against the `User-Agent` for search bots like:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (googlebot|bingbot|yahoo!\sslurp) is_search_bot

<Directory /docroot>
    Order Deny,Allow

    Deny from 3.0.0.0/8
    Deny from 4.0.0.0/25
    Deny from 4.0.0.128/26
    Deny from 4.0.0.192/28
    Deny from 4.0.0.208/29

    Allow from env=is_search_bot
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but if you really don't what google to index it then use a robot.txt file so it doesn't index it. The robot.txt would be

```
User-agent: googlebot Disallow: /directory/
```

If it's just a matter of blocking US ip and that's it then you're probably good, as google has data centers in many different locations, not just the United States. This means that google will still probably index it.

Answer (score 0):

Although google has many data centers , but all their bots are in US so no google will not be able to scan your website if you block us ips

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access your domain root directory, just use this [meta tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710) to block google bot index specific page(s):

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

If your site was indexed already by google crawler, following the guide [Remove your own content from Google search results](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663416)

Answer (score 0):

Access: https://www.google.com/webmasters/

There all information that you need.

Here, the Google teach how you can block the Googlebot index your site:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93708

About your question, I think that if you block all US IP Address, the "Google other country" must access and index your site, then he must sync with Google US.